# How can you print an inequality sign without quotes?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way I can make the output display the proper text. When I have tried this the inequality sign do not show up unless you put `"` around it and it displays the quotes too. Is there a way it can not print the parenthesis and still display the `>` or `<` sign?

The code I am trying to use looks like the following...

```
set /p projectname=Enter Project Name:  
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Output
echo  <html> >>%projectname%.html
echo  <head> >>%projectname%.html
echo  <link rel="stylesheet" href="%projectname%.css">">>%projectname%.html
echo  </head> >>%projectname%.html
```

I want the output to look like the following...

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="(project name).css">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape characters in batch scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854779/escape-characters-in-batch-scripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape each redirector that is to be `echo`ed as text with `^` Thus: `^<` or `^>`

for instance

```
echo  ^<head^> >>%projectname%.html
```

or better (no trailing space)

```
>>%projectname%.html echo  ^<head^>
```

or better still

```
(
 echo whatever
 echo whatever else
 echo whatever else again
)>filename
```

where `>` becomes `>>` to append (> means 'create file anew')

(only need to redirect to file once)